# Are there any traditional Jewish sources that indicate one should investigate the truth of Judaism and follow his conclusions?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, faith-bitachon-emunah, ikarim

As noted [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18653/how-can-we-be-sure-that-judaism-is-true-the-truth), the evidence for Judaism is subject to dispute. The most intellectually honest approach to this question would seem to require one to thoroughly investigate the matter and follow his well-researched conclusion. This logic should extend to telling someone to follow his conclusion, even should he conclude, say, Catholicism is true.

However, though some Rishonim provide proofs for Judaism, I have not found any Rishonim echo this claim of mine. Further, they often seem to present these proofs as means of fulfilling the mitzvah of Emunah and perhaps silencing doubts, not as a "neutral" approach (see beginning of [Aaliyah's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79412/16735) in the aforementioned post) to help one clarify whether or *not* Judaism is correct.

For instance, I have yet to find a Rishon who endorsed a comparative religion study. And yet, this approach would seem to be most honest and sensible to me.

Thus,

1. Why is this idea not expressed by the Rishonim? What's wrong with my way of thinking?
2. Please provide sources if it is.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.2.3?lang=bi

Comment: I wouldn't be able to find it now, but the Moreh Nevuchim says clearly that if full investigation showed something different (he's talking about the world existing forever) from the current way the Torah is understood, we would _of course_ begin understanding it in that way.

Comment: "Your way of thinking", btw, is very fully expressed in John Stuart Mills' On Liberty, in the chapter on Freedom of Speech. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Liberty He distinguishes clearly between free discussion where the "right answer" is predetermined, and where the freedom to discuss includes the conclusion.

Comment: Yehuda, do you not see the flaw in this logic? Jewish sources must be believed first in order to empower them as valid sources for any obligation or permission. Jewish sources can't obligate one to believe, or give valid permission to not believe _themselves_! One has to already believe in God before one will accept a commandment from Him to believe in Him. Of course then, the Rabbonim assume one believes if one is relying on them already, and thus are not going to entertain the possibility that the Torah can be abandoned.

Comment: @shmosel You hit a sore point- I always had trouble accepting that Rambam. How can any religion mandate one to ignore his sincere questions about its veracity?

Comment: @RabbiKaii I think you make an excellent point. I've considered this and I imagine it's most of the answer. Can you post as an answer? Still, consider the following scenario. If your teenage child told you he was struggling with religion and wanted to investigate the matter, and he asked you if this decision to investigate is his moral right, how would you respond? I'm not sure how I would respond. But a large part of me would acknowledge that it is, and would not only see it as his moral right but as his moral obligation (despite the fear it would engender for me).

Comment: Thus, I would expect some whiff of this somewhere in the Torah. In particular, there is a large body of evidence for belief in the Torah. Wouldn't a religion marked by honesty and moral integrity encourage the person to investigate and discover the truth? And just like a father would be conflicted to encourage his son to do so, say, because he already underwent his own investigation and concluded Judaism is correct, I would imagine part of him would express some degree of encouragement... Do you see where I'm coming from?

Comment: עד מתי אתם פסחים על שתי הסעפים אם ה האלהים לכו אחריו ואם הבעל לכו אחריו. This verse can be construed to express my point but I assume it doesn't mean what I'm saying.

Comment: @MichoelR Thanks for the source in the Moreh! Please post when you find exact location. Not sure what you're referring to about John Stuart Mills..can you elaborate?

Comment: @Yehuda yes I think I do. I have a few avenues to pursue when I get the time bli neder

Comment: Do you really need to investigate "catholicism". A simply surface look shows that they don't worship G-d alone and a logical person would conclude whatever "religion" must be true must worship G-d and not any lesser being. Moreover, what makes the standard for investigating Judaism? If you are limited to your intelectual abilities then you will always be limited as a creation. Another point is how much time will this end up being spent studying heretical ideas that can G-d forbid sway your "intellectual" pursuit which for a personal cannot be wholly separate from emotions?

Comment: @Dude Your brief argument has not convinced me- I guess I am not "logical". I think there are many intelligent Catholics- I'm curious what they'd respond. I think your "moreover" question, if I understand it, is compelling. But we don't apply that reasoning to any other area of our lives, i.e., we still do some investigation. (See Rabbi Dovid Gottlieb's Living Up to the Truth.) I think your last point seems to be comprised of two arguments: being wrongly swayed and emotional bias. To 1- that's obviously a risk one must take. To 2- do you think it's impossible to achieve objectivity?

Comment: https://www.bartleby.com/130/2.html "The Catholic Church has its own way of dealing with this embarrassing problem. It makes a broad separation between those who can be permitted to receive its doctrines on conviction, and those who must accept them on trust. Neither, indeed, are allowed any choice as to what they will accept; but the clergy, such at least as can be fully confided in, may admissibly and meritoriously make themselves acquainted with the arguments of opponents, in order to answer them, and may, therefore, read heretical books; the laity, not unless by special permission"

Comment: I think Chovot HaLevavot expects you after having learned about Judaism via tradition, to study it for yourself to determine what is true and what is not.

Comment: @MichoelR Thank you, that is fascinating.

Answer (score 2):

In the outset of the [Kuzari](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kuzari.1?lang=bi), Rabbi Yehuda HaLevi (1075 – 1141) presents some rudimentary arguments of why one shouldn't accept some of the basic premises of Christianity and Islam vis a vis Judaism. Given that the foundation of Christianity and Islam are primarily based on 'revelation' to individual humans, which is hard to verify.

I imagine that given that Judaism predates Christianity and Islam, and given that our tradition claims an unbroken chain, it seems reasonable that Rishonim didn't tackle foundational elements of faith given basic stumbling blocks such as those outlined by the Kuzari. Nonetheless, there were various points in history where Judaism was challenged and Jewish scholars did have to outline arguments against the extent religions of the day. Pirkei Avot instructs us to "know what to respond to an apikoros" ([Avot 2:14)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.2.14?lang=bi), perhaps for exactly this reason. In a sense, this mishna is endorsing the study of anything that would be required to respond to someone challenging Judaism.

Furthermore, over the years I have heard numerous discourses focusing on [Deuteronomy 13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.13?lang=bi&aliyot=0) which instructs us not to harken to the words of "dreamers of dreams" i.e., false 'prophets'. The Torah itself, tells us this. In this regard, any person who instructs a Jew to go against the unbroken tradition as outlined in Tanach and chazal falls in this category. There are various commentaries which relate this perek directly to Jesus and Mohammed (I need to find the source again).

There were however, a number of Rishonim who, by necessity had to undergo public debates to defend the veracity of Judaism as challenged by various religious institutions present in that time and location. For example, the [Disputation of Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputation_of_Paris) where the chief rabbi Yechiel of Paris defended Judaism in 1240, [Disputation of Barcelona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputation_of_Barcelona) (year 1263, Ramban) and the Disputation of Tortosa (years 1413-1414, Hasdai Crescas, later than Rishonim...).

So although those Rishonim didn't, per se, endorse "comparative religious studies", they knew how to defend Judaism against their primarily Christian interlocutors.

Answer (score 2):

*Why is this idea not expressed by the Rishonim? What's wrong with my way of thinking*?

The idea isn't expressed in Rishonim due to the intrinsic problems with studying heresy. See the last perek of Sanhedrin and the second perek of Chagiga for more detail.

What's wrong with the way of thinking is that history has shown that is doesn't work. As the Gemora says (when discussing the prohibition of delving into it) "heresy is compelling" That is true regardless of what the heresy is actually saying.

Thousands of years of Jewish history has shown that those who go off OTD claiming to be truth seekers who couldn't find answers in Orthodox Judaism have almost always  ended  up believing whatever was preached by the intelligentsia or the masses of the time and place they happened to have found themselves in. Makes no difference whether they believed in. Could have been Catholicism, Islam, idolatry  the world has always existed etc. etc. etc. the belief varied greatly, the claim of "as a truth seeker I can't avoid this conclusion" remained constant and unchanged. Another thing that remain unchanged was that the "truth seekers" only flourished in societies that allowed free entry to the upper middle class. Otherwise the OTD movements preached an anti establishment message. Because the  host culture only wins over believers when they are offering something in return.

Therefore the results of telling people to study comparative religion (and presumably atheism) for the sake of intellectual honesty is just going to be mass assimilation to their host culture. Also for ostensible  "intellectual honesty"

That said the Mishna in Pirkey Avos 2:14  says וְדַע מַה שֶּׁתָּשִׁיב You do need to know what answer heretics. Not just brush them away with "they don't know what they are talking about"

Comment: Great answer. You left out a big one: communism! And on your last paragraph, see this comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132813/how-come-the-world-was-doing-avodah-zara-while-noach-and-shem-were-still-alive/132814#comment440184_132814

Comment: Communism was included in the anti establishment movements that took off in  societies that wasn't allowing entry to the upper middle class anyway

Comment: @Schmerel Thanks for the superb answer. You've explained the problem (both religious and practical) with societal engagement in studying heterical subjects for "the sake of truth-seeking". But the alternative is also quite difficult- how can someone honest believe if he doesn't feel he has done an honest investigation? Also, do you think it's humanly possible to overcome these biases?

Comment: That is an issue but it is a universal and circular  one. It's very rare to find someone from any group who seriously searches through all the major world belief systems and comes to a conclusion radically different than  what is believed or at least  considered acceptable thought anywhere  near him. I've never seen anyone question Western though or scientific belief on the basis of "had I grown up in the far east I would see things differently. Maybe they really are right"

Comment: @Schmerel I agree it is universal and rare; in what way is it circular? Also, just because of the rarity of such a truth-seeker, does that mean it is not correct? In particular, if someone is driven to "figure this out", should we discourage him?

Comment: @Schmerel Sure you have. You've seen many of those people. They [nearly] all question Western thought, look into other things, and decide that Western thought is right. Just because you don't see people leaving Science doesn't mean they don't question it. What you've written here is the opposite of a compelling belief system. A compelling belief system is one that you aren't worried about people questioning, since it has good basis.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you for that excellent point. The fear that religions often have about self-examination and investigation, as expressed via their doctrine or culture, make the honest seeker question their truth even further. This was a part of the impetus to my question- the very fact that this idea does not seem to be expressed by the Rishonim frankly bothers me, because a religion that believes in itself and does not feel threatened by questions should, to the contrary, encourage them.

Comment: @Schmerel Another point: you noted that it's very rare to find someone [of this nature]. Avraham Avinu completely questioned the status quo in his time and we celebrate him for that. Shouldn't the celebration go both ways? Do we only celebrate people questioning polytheism and not those questioning monotheism, even if the common qualities both types of people possess is honesty and courage?

Comment: You can ask the same question on the scientific community. They also laud the first ones to challenge the  then conventional scientific belief and discover something  new but   strongly  denigrate those  who questions their current beliefs and claims. “Conspiracy theorist” is an insult by most Americans even that also requires questioning the current belief system and a willingness to  accept  counter evidence that the mainstream around you does not . I know this this does not answer your question. Its just to  give more perspective.

Answer (score 1):

In his Sefer Haikarim, [R' Yosef Albo weighs in on this question](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_1.24.1?lang=en):

> We must call attention here to a question concerning religious belief.
> Is a person who professes a given religion permitted, or obliged, to
> investigate the principles of his religion in order to see whether
> they are true and in agreement with what we have laid down concerning
> the principles of divine law or not? And assuming that he is permitted
> to do this, has he the right to choose that religion which seems to
> him the truer or not? Whichever alternative we adopt offers great
> difficulties.  In the first place, if we say that one professing a
> religion is obliged to investigate the principles of his religion, or
> is permitted to institute a comparison between the principles of his
> religion and those of another, the result will be that no religionist
> will be firm in his belief, and will therefore deserve no reward for
> belief, if he is not firm therein and free from doubt. For we can not
> call a thing belief except when the mind can not conceive the thing
> being otherwise, as we explained before. But if he investigates, he
> shows thereby that he is in doubt. And if we grant that he is
> permitted to investigate, suppose he has investigated and compared the
> principles of his religion with those of another, and found the
> principles of the other religion truer than those of his own, is he
> permitted to exchange his religion for the other? If he is permitted,
> the result will be that no man professing a religion can be made happy
> or be saved by his belief. For if, having compared the principles of
> his religion with those of the other and found the latter truer than
> his own, he has exchanged his religion for the other, it is still
> impossible for him to be firm in the belief of the other religion
> which he has chosen, because it is possible that after another
> investigation and a comparison between the second religion and a
> third, he may find the principles of the latter more satisfactory, and
> will have to change the second for the third, and in the same way the
> third for the fourth and the fourth for the fifth, and so on
> indefinitely. The result will be that no man will be firm in his
> belief until he has completed his investigation of all the religions
> in the world and chosen one in preference to all the rest. But there
> is the possibility that there is a religion at the extreme end of the
> inhabited world which is unknown to him, and which is truer than all
> the rest. No man therefore can be saved by his belief. For he can not
> have perfect faith until he has investigated all religions, and he can
> not investigate all religions, as we have seen. It would seem then
> that a person should not be allowed to investigate the principles of
> his religion so as to reach sure belief.  But if our conclusion is
> that one is not allowed to investigate the principles of his religion,
> then one of two things must be true. Either all religions lead to
> human happiness, and one has no advantage over the other in the matter
> of reward and punishment, since no one is allowed to investigate the
> principles of his religion nor to change it for another. But it is
> quite impossible that religions which are directly opposed, the one
> affirming what the other denies, the one trinitarian, the other
> monotheistic, should equally lead to happiness. On the other hand, if
> we say that they do not both lead to happiness, but one of them only,
> a great absurdity will follow, namely that God is guilty of injustice
> (Heaven forbid!) in punishing those who profess a false religion,
> claiming to be divine, since the believer has no right to budge from
> his religion, or to change it for another, or to entertain any doubt
> concerning it. This difficulty applies to all divine religions and we
> must try to solve it.  Our solution of this question is as follows: If
> it were true that all the known religions of the world are opposed to
> one another, every one saying that the other is not divine, the
> question we raised would be a difficult one indeed and hard to solve.
> But since all religions agree in accepting the divinity of one of
> them, the only objection to it being that, according to them, it was
> temporary in character and its time has passed, our opinion is that
> every one should investigate the principles of his religious belief.
> This applies without any doubt to those religions which are opposed to
> the one divine law, for no one should allow himself to be persuaded to
> believe something in opposition to the admittedly divine law, except
> after an investigation of the law, the second or the third, which he
> is inclined to believe, and the principles thereof, as we explained in
> the eighteenth chapter of this Book.  As for the admittedly divine
> law, one who professes it should also inquire whether it is temporary
> or eternal; and if it should turn out not to be eternal, wherein the
> change is likely to occur.  This is also Maimonides’ reason for saying
> in the fortieth chapter of the second book of the Guide of the
> Perplexed that it behooves every one to investigate the religion which
> he professes. He says there that the investigation should embrace two
> aspects. First, the religion itself. He must examine the commands and
> prohibitions, and if he finds that their sole purpose is to remove
> wrongdoing and violence and to maintain order in the affairs of the
> state, he must know that it is a conventional and not a divine law.
> If, on the other hand, he finds that in addition to removing
> wrongdoing and violence, it also takes care to inculcate true ideas
> about God and the angels, and endeavors to enlighten mankind and to
> awaken them to the nature of truth in relation to all things, that
> shows it is divine. The second aspect of investigation is that of the
> founder of the law in question. The alleged prophet or messenger who
> claims that the law is transmitted through him by God must be examined
> with a view to determine whether his claim is genuine or whether the
> contents of his law are borrowed from some one else. The thing to
> examine is the man’s character and conduct. The best test of
> genuineness is that he abstains from corporeal indulgences and holds
> them in contempt, especially the sense of touch, which is a disgrace
> to us, as Aristotle said. This is the gist of Maimonides’ words in
> that chapter.  When he says that a test of the law itself is, if it
> takes pains to inculcate true ideas about God, etc., he is alluding to
> that religion which ascribes to God corporeality and trinity. And when
> he speaks of testing the moral qualities of the founder of the
> religion, he is alluding to that man who claimed that he was a prophet
> of the Arabs. According to Arab accounts he was addicted to physical
> and sexual indulgence. But this is not sufficient to enable us to
> differentiate a law laid down by a wise man, containing true
> principles such as a divine law might have, the founder himself being
> a man of noble character and conduct, from a divine law. There is no
> way of telling whether it is really a divine law or a human law which
> resembles a divine.  My opinion therefore is that the two-fold
> examination of which Maimonides speaks is to be understood in the
> following way. First, the principles of the religion in question must
> be examined, to see whether they agree with the principles of divine
> law which we have mentioned. Also the secondary principles derived
> from the first must be examined, as we explained in the fifteenth
> chapter of this Book. If we find that the religion in question is in
> agreement with, or at least not in opposition to, the primary and
> secondary principles, and at the same time it endeavors to suppress
> wrongdoing and to inculcate true ideas among the people instead of the
> foolish fancies in vogue among women and common people, and to arouse
> them to a desire for human perfection, that shows it is divine.
> Similarly our Rabbis say in Torat Kohanim: Rabbi Akiba said, Thou
> shalt love thy neighbour as thyself is a great principle of the Torah.
> Ben Azzai said, This is the book of the generations of Adam is a
> greater principle of the Torah than that. By this is meant to indicate
> that a divine law must embrace both topics, the suppression of
> wrongdoing and violence among the inhabitants of the land, as alluded
> to in the expression, Thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself, and
> the directing of the attention of the people to true ideas and to
> human perfection, which is alluded to in the verse beginning, This is
> the book of the generations of Adam, which continues with the words,
> In the day that God created man, in the likeness of God made He him,
> indicating that man has a human form which is in the likeness of God.
> And therefore he must be careful not to disgrace it, either in his own
> person or in the person of his neighbor, and he must see to it that it
> should survive death and unite with the celestial beings in the place
> from which it originally came. All this a divine law should contain.
> But it is still possible that it is the work of a wise man or wise
> men. We must therefore examine it from another aspect, namely the
> manner in which the messenger proved his authenticity, as one sent by
> God to transmit a law. If this matter is proved in a direct manner, as
> we explained in the eighteenth chapter of this book, the law is
> divine; if not, it is spurious and merely pretends to be divine, even
> though it acknowledges all principles, primary and derived, much more
> so if it opposes them or any one of them.

I am not quite sure what his answer is.